# TypeORM relation error on restart of the server

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I am working with `NestJS + TypeOrm + Postgres`, this is something I have never come across.

**Problem:**

When I have a completely clean db with no migrations and schema, and I start my application server all the migrations run successfully and schema is created. Then if I shutdown and restart my server the I see the following error

`QueryFailedError: relation "prospect" already exists`

I am not sure what could be the possible **root cause** of this issue?

---

Here is my config of my ORM

```
# ORM VARIABLES
TYPEORM_CONNECTION = postgresql
TYPEORM_HOST = localhost
TYPEORM_USERNAME = test
TYPEORM_PASSWORD = something
TYPEORM_DATABASE = onboarding
TYPEORM_PORT = 5432
TYPEORM_SYNCHRONIZE = false
TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS = dist/src/database/migrations/*.js
TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS_RUN = true
TYPEORM_LOGGING = true
TYPEORM_ENTITIES = src/**/*.entity.ts
TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS_DIR = src/database/migrations
```

I have one migration script, which looks like

```
export class prospectInit1626978958486 implements MigrationInterface {
  name = 'prospectInit1626978958486'

  public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
    await queryRunner.query(`CREATE SCHEMA prospect`)
    await queryRunner.query(
      `CREATE TABLE "prospect"."prospect" ("id" uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(), "external_id" character varying, "createdOn" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT now(), "modifiedOn" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT now(), "deletedOn" TIMESTAMP, "clientFirstName" character varying NOT NULL, "clientLastName" character varying NOT NULL, "clientEmail" character varying NOT NULL, "advisorFirstName" character varying, "advisorLastName" character varying, "advisorEmail" character varying NOT NULL, "advisorRrCode" character varying NOT NULL, "idVerifierFirstName" character varying, "idVerifierLastName" character varying, "idVerifierEmail" character varying NOT NULL, "firmId" character varying NOT NULL, "sendClientEmailNotification" boolean NOT NULL, "onboardingHashedPassword" character varying NOT NULL, "extensors" jsonb, CONSTRAINT "UQ_2cedabc8670a41b3b33fcb93c15" UNIQUE ("external_id"), CONSTRAINT "UQ_2e4c0cd5497385413c0037cb2f6" UNIQUE ("clientEmail"), CONSTRAINT "PK_96a40a8754e69a1ffa6930deb07" PRIMARY KEY ("id"))`,
    )
    await queryRunner.query(
      `CREATE INDEX "IDX_2cedabc8670a41b3b33fcb93c1" ON "prospect"."prospect" ("external_id") `,
    )
  }

  public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
    await queryRunner.query(
      `DROP INDEX "prospect"."IDX_2cedabc8670a41b3b33fcb93c1"`,
    )
    await queryRunner.query(`DROP TABLE "prospect"."prospect"`)
    await queryRunner.query(`DROP SCHEMA prospect`)
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

More from error stack

```
    at TCP.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
  length: 102,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '42P07',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'heap.c',
  line: '1164',
  routine: 'heap_create_with_catalog'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you have a prospect entity in your database, TypeORM tries to create it again. In order to clean your database, can you try maybe delete the migration tables and all existing migration files and regenerating them with

`typeorm migration:create`

Be careful, it will delete all your data but since you cleaned your DB I guess there will be no problem for you

Comment: So we tried clearing our schema and migration table, and on a clean db we run the application server and it all works fine. But when we restart the server again, the error comes back, if i am not wrong even if a schema exists it should not complain. It's the consecutive server starts where the issue is

Comment: Sorry for my late response, what about adding 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS' ?